# Norm Used in Perturbation Matrix Theory?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My question is that what is the type of 2-Norm used in Weyl's theorem for relative perturbation? Is that a induced norm, or a entry-wise norm?

$\epsilon=\|X^T X-I\|_2$, where relative difference in eigenvalues $\leq \epsilon.$

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a norm induced by the Euclidean 2-norm. In other words, for any $A\in M_n(\mathbb C)$, $\|A\|_2=\max_{x\in\mathbb C^n,\,\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|_2$. Equivalently, $\|A\|_2$ is the largest singular value of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter; any operator norm (also known as induced norm) works. This is because if $\| \cdot \|$ is any operator norm and $\rho$ denotes spectral radius then $\rho(A) \leq \| A \|$.

Comment: As the answer by user1551 says, I think also this it does matter, and it should be induced norm, not entry-wise ones.

Comment: @SeyyedHosseinMousavi I said operator/induced norm. Would it have been clearer if I'd said "it doesn't matter as long as it's an operator norm"?